# Split a flux into grouped fluxes, replay or cache each grouped flux, and then merge

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I've got a stream of weather messages, each message containing a site ID and bunch of weather related parameters.  New messages are coming in from three or four different sites every 5 minutes.

I want to construct a flux that splits the messages into separate fluxes based on the site ID, cache or replay the last 12 messages for each site, and then merge them back into a single flux for subscribers.

I've tried the following, emitting 30 messages on the weatherMessagesSink and then subscribing, all messages are received by the first subscribe.  However a second subscribe() doesn't receive any of the cached messages but does receive new messages that are subsequently emitted on the sink.

```
weatherMessagesSink
  .asFlux()
  .groupBy(weatherMessage -> weatherMessage.getSiteID())
  .flatMap(groupedFlux -> groupedFlux.cache(12)
```

A simpler approach might be to just replay the last 4 * 12 messages but that's a bit brittle if sites are added or removed.  Also if messages come in at different rates for each site then it will also mean there are a different number of messages cached for each site.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more searching, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71883223/18220774) from [Andrew Sasha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6329755/andrew-sasha?tab=profile) and some trial and error I've found the following to work as required.

```
weatherMessagesSink
        .asFlux()
        .groupBy(weatherMessage -> weatherMessage.getSite())
        .map(groupedFlux -> groupedFlux.cache(12))
        .cache()
        .flatMap(groupedFlux -> groupedFlux);
```

As a relative newcomer to Project Reactor I didn't find this particularly obvious but I think I understand what it's doing now.  Hopefully this will be of use to others that are looking to solve a similar problem.